# Remove record when value is empty on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app where Users can create baskets with many asset_allocations in it.

Basket Model

```
class Basket < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :asset_allocations, :dependent => :delete_all
    validates :name, presence: true
    validates_uniqueness_of :name, allow_blank: true

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :asset_allocations, :reject_if => lambda {|a| a[:ratio].blank?}, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

AssetAllocation Model

```
class AssetAllocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :basket

  validates :ratio, :numericality => { :greater_than => 0 }, allow_blank: true
end
```

The above code works perfectly on creating new record (it ignores all asset_allocation when ratio is empty), but how can I delete the records in asset_allocation table when the value of the ratio is empty? 

Lets say, on edit form I changed the value of ***allocation2*** from 56 to empty and ***allocation3*** will be a new record and then hitting update button should delete ***allocation2*** from database and insert ***allocation3***.

[Sample Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2BP0.jpg)

Comment: I am guessing you will need a before_filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Fallenhero is right.

Since you already have **allow_destroy** option with your accept_nested_attributes, all you have to do is add _destroy: true in before_filter to the nested member you want to delete depending on your condition.

```
before_action :add_destroy_option

def add_destroy_option
  params[:basket][:asset_allocations].each_with_index do |a, i|
    params[:basket][:asset_allocations][i][:_destroy] = a[:value].nil?
  end
end
```

Or if you don't want to add a filter in your controller, you can also set this **_destroy** parameter in your frontend as per your condition using jQuery